# How do I view the Tensorflow Memory Profiler tool in the TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, tensorboard

I'm having Out of Memory issues during TensorFlow training. I'd like to use the [TensorFlow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#overview_page) to help diagnose this, in particular the [Memory profile tool](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#memory_profile_tool).

I have followed the [quick-start guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler#quick-start), and it works, but my Tensorboard is showing everything except the memory profiler.

In my tools list, I can see memory pipeline analyzer, tensorflow stats, trace viewer, kernel stats, but no memory profiler.

[image: Tools list]

Is there anything in particular I need to do to launch the TensorFlow profiler with the memory profile tool?

Answer (score 0):

(OK this is kind of embarrassing...)

The data in that picture is the example data that comes pre-loaded with TensorFlow Profiler.

My mistake was that I needed to start the profiling just before I start training my model, see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#profiling_apis) for the API. I assumed Profiler didn't need an API hook.

After adding this code, I can click the 'Capture Profile' button on TensorBoard and then on the 'Runs' dropdown I can select the data captured from my model.